# Android preferences onclick event using sherlockpreferenceactivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

hello am trying to implement an onclick event for CheckBoxPreference.
In the folder res/xml/preferences.xml i have this preference:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
android:key="IsEnable"
android:title="IsEnable"
android:persistent="true"
/>
```

i followed this answer on SO:
[Android preferences onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330677/android-preferences-onclick-event)

In the activity.java:

```
public class settingsActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("IsEnable");
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {//<--compilation error
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
//code goes here
return true;
}
});
}
```

But am getting the below compile error at the 7th line:
Multiple markers at this line
    - OnPreferenceClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method setOnPreferenceClickListener(Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener) in the type Preference is not applicable for the 
     arguments (new OnPreferenceClickListener(){})

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import it too? Check if you have this line

```
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
```