# How to have an onclick on preferences that call a sqlite method?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my preferences page I would like to delete all information stored in the database at any given time.

How would I put an `onclick` event when the preference is clicked on? The `onClick` should result in calling the delete method from my `sqlite` database. I have tried looking on the internet but nothing works for me. This is not a duplicate because, I have tried that already and it does not work as it is depreciated and there are no other answers with a call back to java

Can you please show me the code I would use because I do not understand what to do?

**preferences.xml (for onClick)**

```
<Preference android:title="@string/delete_all_expense"
    android:summary="@string/delete_all_expense_detail"
    android:key="delete_all_expense"
    />
```

**PreferenceActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }



    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

**Delete method form DatabaseHelper (If you need it)**

```
public void deleteAllExpense(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table" + TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android preferences onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330677/android-preferences-onclick-event)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because, I have tried that already and it does not work as it is depreciated and there are no other answers with a call back to java

Comment: did you read the comments there?

Comment: PreferenceFragment.findPreference is not deprecated (as of API level 23, current at the time of writing). So, findPreference itself is not deprecated; it is the direct use of PreferenceActivity which is deprecated. Google want us to move to PreferenceFragment instead, not to abandon findPreference

Comment: I get the error 'Non-static method 'findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)' cannot be referenced from a static context', when I use this.

Comment: why do you have your fragment in the same file as your activity?

Comment: Is that wrong, I don't know, what should I do?

Comment: It's a really bad practice, you should have it in a separate file and it shouldn't be static class

Comment: Is that why this is not working as it is supposed to?

Comment: Yes that's why you are having the error about Non-static method, althought you can also say this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); instead of addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working for you, you can implement your own Preference like this:

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setOnPreferenceClickListener(this)
    }


    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
        //delete your data
        return true
    }
}
```

adding it to your .xml layout with:

```
<your.package.name.CustomPreference
    etc.../>
```